# Custom interval is not working

Tags: plugins, wp-cron

I am trying to create custom interval for cron schedule with given user input, but its not working.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_cron_schedule' );
function custom_cron_schedule( $schedules,$int ) {
    $schedules['custom'] = array(
        'interval' => $int, // user input integer in second
        'display'  => __( 'Custom Interval' ),
    );

    return $schedules;
}
```

I tried to look at custom schedule via `_get_cron_array()` and found that interval is missing I also checked `$int`, it has `36000`.

So what am I missing here OR am I not allowed to use arguments in this filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Note on input arguments:

You are using the *filter callback function* (FCB) with *two* input arguments, but the default is *one*.

In general you should replace:

```
add_filter( 'some_filter', 'some_filter_callback' );
function some_filter_callback( $arg1, $arg2 ) {
```

with something like:

```
add_filter( 'some_filter', 'some_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
function some_filter_callback( $arg1, $arg2 ) {
```

if you want two arguments.

You would also have to look at the `apply_filters( 'some_filter', ... )` part to find the correct number of input arguments.

### The problem:

When you check the source of `wp_get_schedules()` you find the following:

```
return array_merge( apply_filters( 'cron_schedules', array() ), $schedules );
```

so there's no second `$int` argument passed on to the FCB.

The array that you return from your FCB is then merged with the default `$schedules`, where:

```
$schedules = array(
        'hourly'     => array( 'interval' => HOUR_IN_SECONDS,      'display' => __( 'Once Hourly' ) ),
        'twicedaily' => array( 'interval' => 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS, 'display' => __( 'Twice Daily' ) ),
        'daily'      => array( 'interval' => DAY_IN_SECONDS,       'display' => __( 'Once Daily' ) ),
    );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, I tried to use following function but still no success, Please can you help me with a example for my problem ? CODE: function cron_interval($int){return array('custom'=>array('interval'=> $int,'display'=>'custom'))}

Comment: You can use the *Options API* (`set_option`/`get_option`) or *Custom User Meta* (`set_user_meta`/`get_user_meta`) to store and retrieve the user input data. You could also consider wrapping your code into a class to make it easier.

Comment: finally I found the problem, its variable scope, I am calling this function inside a class function so its not working but now I make that $int variable global so its working ...silly mistake by me...thanks for your help birgire

Comment: yes it's the scope, but I don't recommend solving this by adding a global variable. If you are constructing a class, use  for example `$this->interval`.